# How to parse special characters in python's ArgumentParser()?

Tags: python-2.7, parsing, arguments, argparse

I am working with an application that receives parameters like a ":" separated string as node ID and a flow name that may contain several special characters. When I want to parse the arguments an error is triggered due to some issues with special characters like *. This is an example input:

```
python flowapp.py --remove 00:00:02:84:75:e2:95:42 UDP*node-3_to_node-4*dp9000__@node-1
```

Here is the code I am using to parse option "--remove" :

```
parser.add_argument("-r","--remove",help="remove the specified flow\
entry from a given node",nargs='2')
```

When I execute the app I get the following errors:

```
...
start_index = consume_optional(start_index)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1858, in consume_optional
arg_count = match_argument(action, selected_patterns)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2011, in _match_argument
nargs_pattern = self._get_nargs_pattern(action)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2176, in _get_nargs_pattern
nargs_pattern = '(-*%s-*)' % '-*'.join('A' * nargs)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Is there a way to tell python's argparser to interpret characters like -, * or @ as special characters and not "math" operators?

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the special characters.  The `sys.argv` will be something like:

```
['flowapp.py', '--remove', '00:00:02:84:75:e2:95:42', 'UDP*node-3_to_node-4*dp9000__@node-1']
```

which `argparse` should have no problems handling.

The problem is with the string argument to `nargs`:

```
parser.add_argument("-r","--remove",...,nargs='2')
```

As part of parsing it constructs an argument matching pattern, which depends on the `nargs` value:

```
nargs_pattern = '(-*%s-*)' % '-*'.join('A' * nargs)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

If `nargs` is one of the special values like `*`, it must be an integer.  You gave it a string.

```
 parser.add_argument("-r","--remove",...,nargs=2)
```

In other versions of `argparse`, you might get a different error:

```
 ValueError: length of metavar tuple does not match nargs
```

But it's the same issue.